# Can't use a superglobal directly within a require string path

Tags: php

I'd like to include a file, at a path relative to the root of the website. The simplest, most readable way I could think of was:

```
require "$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/helpers/NumberHelper.php";
```

Which I expected to work since I'm using double quotes, so I should be able to use the variable directly within the string. Unfortunately though, this yields a few fairly unhelpful errors:

```
Warning POSSIBLE Syntax Error (check preceding valid syntax error)  unexpected: '"' VisitorLog.php  C:/xampp/htdocs/ExtTests/VisitorLog.php:3
Warning POSSIBLE Syntax Error (check preceding valid syntax error)  unexpected: ;   VisitorLog.php  C:/xampp/htdocs/ExtTests/VisitorLog.php:3
Warning POSSIBLE Syntax Error (check preceding valid syntax error)  unexpected: String  VisitorLog.php  C:/xampp/htdocs/ExtTests/VisitorLog.php:3
Error   Syntax error  unexpected:   String  after:  [  expected:    identifier, variable, NUM_STRING, define    VisitorLog.php  C:/xampp/htdocs/ExtTests/VisitorLog.php:3
```

It's saying it's expecting a `string` after the opening brace, but there is a (single quoted) string there!

The best alternative I could find was:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/helpers/NumberHelper.php";
```

But that's not near as neat (in my opinion).

Why does the first line not work, and is there any way to place a variable directly within a string to achieve what I'm going for?

Comment: variant `"{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/helpers/NumberHelper.php"` but doesn't really matter, they do the same thing, this is just personal preference, your alternative ain't bad either

Comment: @Ghost What do the curly braces do? Are they just acting as a grouper to help it parse it? Why is it getting confused on the first version?

Comment: yes, it acts as the grouper to reference it as an array